# How do I get the comment ID in a template file?

Tags: comments

I want to show the comment title linked to the comment permalink.
This is the content of the comment.html.twig file.

```
 <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('comment__content') }}>
    {% if title %}
      {{ title_prefix }}
      <h3{{ title_attributes }}><a href="#comment-{{comment.id}}">{{ title | render | striptags}}</a></h3>
      {{ title_suffix }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ content }}    
  </div>
```

`{{comment.id}}` didn't work. How do I get the comment ID?

Comment: Call it as a function `{{ comment.id() }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[template_preprocess_comment()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/9.2.x) sets the following value, which is essentially the string you want to obtain, apart the hash at the beginning.

```php
$variables['attributes']['id'] = 'comment-' . $comment->id();
```

The template file can use that value with `{{ attributes.id }}`.

```
<div{{ content_attributes.addClass('comment__content') }}>
  {% if title %}
    {{ title_prefix }}
    <h3{{ title_attributes }}><a href="#{{ attributes.id }}">{{ title|render|striptags }}</a></h3>
    {{ title_suffix }}
  {% endif %}
  {{ content }}
</div>
```

#### Reference

- [Using attributes in templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates)

Comment: Thank you so much